# phpexcel printing mysql data to excel( printing only 1 row of data on database to excel)

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I want to use the 10autofilter.php from phpexcel, to our program.

But I want a code that will print on excel the datas on our database since its only prints row 1 and doesnt print all data on our mysql please help me you can see the code it only output 1 row.

I think there's a problem here but this works fine on php displaying on browser but just not in excel the output is 1 row.

I have used `$i++` on $row as you can see i dont know what to do.

```
$res = mysql_query("select * from services");
$row = mysql_num_rows($res);

for($i=0; $i<$row; $i++)
{
    $serviceid  = mysql_result($res,$i,"serviceid");
    $servicename  = mysql_result($res,$i,"servicename");
    $contactemail  = mysql_result($res,$i,"contactemail");
    $charge  = mysql_result($res,$i,"charge");
    $contactlastname  = mysql_result($res,$i,"contactlastname");
    $contactmiddlename  = mysql_result($res,$i,"contactmiddlename");
    $yearassistancereceived  = mysql_result($res,$i,"yearassistancereceived");
    $yearestablished  = mysql_result($res,$i,"yearestablished");

    $dataArray = array(
        array(
            $serviceid,
            $servicename,
            $contactemail,
            $charge."     ".$contactmiddlename." ".$contactlastname, 
            $yearassistancereceived, 
            $yearestablished
        )
    );

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($dataArray, NULL, 'A2');
}
```

I also have the error:

> Fatal error. Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_WriterException' with message 'Invalid parameters passed'. why? at the bottom of the error is written C:\xampp\htdocs\DOSTPROJECT\classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\ContentTypes.php on line 263.

This executes and excel file but I have said only 1 row data, I mean whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write every row of data to spreadsheet row #2, then the rows will all overwrite each other. You want to write the first row of data to spreadsheet row #2, the second to spreadsheet row #3, etc

You used $i++ to get each row from the database, but you're not using it when writing to PHPExcel, you're just writing every row array at cell `A2`

```
for($i=0; $i<$row; $i++)
{
    $serviceid  = mysql_result($res,$i,"serviceid");
    $servicename  = mysql_result($res,$i,"servicename");
    $contactemail  = mysql_result($res,$i,"contactemail");
    $charge  = mysql_result($res,$i,"charge");
    $contactlastname  = mysql_result($res,$i,"contactlastname");
    $contactmiddlename  = mysql_result($res,$i,"contactmiddlename");
    $yearassistancereceived  = mysql_result($res,$i,"yearassistancereceived");
    $yearestablished  = mysql_result($res,$i,"yearestablished");

    $dataArray = array(
        array(
            $serviceid,
            $servicename,
            $contactemail,
            $charge."     ".$contactmiddlename." ".$contactlastname, 
            $yearassistancereceived, 
            $yearestablished
        )
    );

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($dataArray, NULL, 'A'.($i+2));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much big help God bless you Sir Mark